# validation for my password field

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5, eloquent

Am trying to do some extra validation for my password field. heres a sample of my code from my controller.

```html
 if (trim($request->password ) == ''){

            $input=$request->except('password');

        else{

                $input=$request->all();
            }


        }
```

I am geeting this error, that says adminUserController does not exist. Could my line of code be wrong? Anybody? when I requested $input=$request->all() it worked but with this I am getting that error.

Comment: It's very hard to say that your controller has the problem, I think you missed in routing. btw, showing us your adminUserController.php (including project path) and your routes may help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many brackets...
`if (trim($request->password ) == ''){` should be

`if (trim($request->password ) == '')`

without the Left Bracket and remove the last `}` bracket as well.